# Android catching camera preview frames while recording video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I have camera object and code of recording video:

```
Camera c = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
c.lock();
c.setPreviewCallback(mPreviewCallback); // catching frames
c.startPreview();
...
MediaRecorder r = new MediaRecorder();
r.setCamera(c);
r.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
r.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
r.setOutputFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "video.mp4").getPath());
r.setVideoFrameRate(10);
r.setVideoSize(640, 480);
r.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
r.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
r.prepare();
r.start();
```

My code also doesn't work. String `r.start()` throws IllegalStateException because of I didn't called method `c.unlock()` before calling `r.setCamera(c)`. So my question is: **How to catch camera preview frames during recording video via MediaRecorder in Android v4.0 and later without (or instead of) using FFmpeg libraries and MediaMuxer & MediaCodec API?**